# Modx revolution: Conditional loading of chunks into website

Tags: modx-revolution

I employ a snippet to get the number of child elements, returning an integer:

```
[[!getChildCount? &id=`12345`]]
```

Depending on the result of this (zero or greater than zero), I want to load two different chunks into my website. Here is my "Modx-Pseudocode" of what I would like to achieve. Been fiddling for hours now and just can't find out about the right syntax. This is what I'd like to write inside the content field:

```
[[!If [[!getChildCount? &id=`45`]] > 0 
then=`[load_chunk_A]` 
else=`[load_chunk_B]`]]
```

Any hints of how this is properly expressed in Modx revolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are talking about [IF extra](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/if) that you should install, if you haven't already done it, to achieve your goal.

```
[[!If?
&subject=`[[!getChildCount? &id=`45`]]`
&operator=`>`
&operand=`0`
&then=`[[!$chunk_A]]` 
&else=`[[!$chunk_B]]`
]]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I will check it out.